# Interpretation of $\neg x = y$ in first order logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic

I'd like to know how you'd interpret the first order expression $\neg x =y$ in plain language. Here of course $x,y$ represent variables within a given structure.

Is this akin to saying $x \ne y$?

Or is it saying that every variable apart from $x$, is equal to $y$?

I'd really appreciate an explanation as well as an example using a particular language & structure.

Comment: Maybe $\lnot x=y$ actually means $\lnot(x=y)$?

Comment: Yeah my initial thought was that there was a mistake and the correct expression is as you wrote it, but in my assigned work it appears in the 'incorrect' form more than once

Comment: The parentheses are not necessary since the expression $\lnot x$ doesn't make sense in the context of first order logic. But I think that in an introductoriy course, they should be used to help the student.

Comment: Well doesn't the $\neg$ imply that the $x$ is true when $y$ is false and vice-versa, so you could say that $x \neq y$, but that feels less informative since it does not imply that $x,y$ are either true or false. Ie. they could be anything.

Comment: @Everstudent In this context, $x$ and $y$ are variables for *objects* (or elements) of some universe.  They are not propositional variables with truth values. Moreover, here the equality symbol is representing literal equality of objects, not equivalence of truth values ($\Leftrightarrow$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\neg x = y$ means $\neg (x = y)$. The reading $(\neg x) = y$ is not possible, because $\neg$ only operates on formulas (= expressions that evaluate as true or false), not terms (= expressions that evaluate to objects).  $x \neq y$ is an abbreviation for $\neg(x = y)$. It is true iff the object denoted by $x$ is not identical with the object denoted by $y$.

For instance, given a language with two individual constants $a$ and $b$, and two structures $\mathfrak{A}_1 = \langle \{0, 1, 2\}, a \mapsto 0, b \mapsto 1 \rangle$, $\mathfrak{A_2} = \langle \{0, 1, 2\}, a \mapsto 0, b \mapsto 0 \rangle$.
Then $\mathfrak{A}_1 \models \neg a = b$, since $a^{\mathfrak{A}_1} = 0 \neq 1 = b^{\mathfrak{A}_1}$, but $\mathfrak{A}_2 \not \models \neg a = b$, since $a^{\mathfrak{A}_2} = 0 = 0 = b^{\mathfrak{A}_2}$.